# Can you move the notification popups? If so, how?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

I am trying to find out how to move the notification area down on my monitor (I've got dual monitors); I would prefer to move them to bottom left of right monitor if possible, If not Center Right of the monitor will do.

Is there a tutorial or some Software that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change Notify-OSD's default position via dconf-editor

Run dconf-editor (type dconf in the Dash's search area) and change Notify-OSD's position to centered-right (there are only two positions available):
apps-->notify-osd-->enter 2 by clicking gravity

[image]

where is [number] can be:
1 - top-right corner
2 - middle-right
3 - bottom-right corner
4 - bottom-left corner
5 - middle-left
6 - top-left corner

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I know i'm slow to reply to this but It worked (well middle right did, rest didnt but its ok); Thank you for this.

Comment: I search dconf, and other key words to look for this utility, and I can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: On my system (12.10 64 bit) only positions 1 and 2 work. The others default to top-right. I would like bottom right as my prefered position.

Comment: On my Ubutnu 22, the value is already set to top-right, but still it would show in top-center