# notify-osd over indicators

Tags: indicator, notify-osd, indicator-sound

[image: Unity notification over indicator aera]

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.04 I experience strange behavior of the volume indication notifcation `notify-osd` over the status bar.

Can I move the notifcation down?

Comment: Look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/108971/can-you-move-the-notification-popups-if-so-how

Comment: i knew this dconf option, but it is not really what i want. i also tried notify-osd configuration and they are still misplaced. top-right is a good position but not this way. im thinking it's a kind of "bug". thank you answering

Comment: I have the same issue in Xubuntu 17.04. Have you filed a bug report?